# C# Syntax: use an interface as a placeholder in a function's inputs

Tags: c#, syntax

I have an interface for a class that I have not implemented yet,

```
interface IMyInterface<T>{
    T f1(T a, T b);
    T f2(T a, T b);
    ...
}
```

And a class,

```
class MyClass
{
    public static IMyInterface<T> myFunction(IMyInterface<T> a, IMyInterface<T> b){...}
}
```

However, this does not seem to work.  How do I set this up so that it stays generic, so long as the api remains the interface's API?

Comment: Can you clarify, what does not seem to work? By chance you want to have different Types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the generic type parameter `<T>` after the function name:

```
public static IMyInterface<T> myFunction<T>(IMyInterface<T> a, IMyInterface<T> b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put T after the class name:

```
interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T f1(T a, T b);
    T f2(T a, T b);
}

class MyClass<T> // <-- note the <T>
{
    public static IMyInterface<T> myFunction(IMyInterface<T> a, IMyInterface<T> b) { return null; }
}
```

Comment: Not a downvoter, but is there some reason the entire class needs to be a generic of type `T`? Maybe a reasonable inference I failed to make from the OP's text?

Comment: upvoted; - OP (got the hang of the interface/type inference)

Comment: @canon the question was unclear. Both answers are correct. .if bordeo wants only that one method tied to T then you are correct.  if bordeo wants the entire class tied to T then my answer is correct. But no... The entire class does not have to be a generic of type T.